# Quick Launch menu spacing

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, editing-menu

the Spacing between the links on the Quick Launch menu is too much, need to condense the spacing, of course, I see no option, the search turns up modify CSS, I have never done the CSS modification before, and need a step by step, I scared of messing it up completely and that would be bad!!!!

Please help and talk very much down to me and explain what i need to do

Answer (score 0):

As you said, if you want to modify the spacing between the links on the "Quick Launch" menu, you need to modify the CSS. **However, modifying CSS is only effective in classic mode, not in modern mode.**

More information, please refer to **[this article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ms466994(v=office.14))**.

`Note:`

In SharePoint Designer 2013, please copy **seattle.master**.

Answer (score 0):

I assume we are talking about the quick launch navigation in the classic experience?

Instead of modifying the master page which is usually not recommended you could add alternate CSS to your page.

Here are the steps required:

- Upload the CSS file to the Site Assets or to another location on your
  SharePoint site.
- Click on the settings gear and select Site settings.
- In the Look and Feel group, click on the link 'Master page'.
- Expand 'Alternate CSS URL'.
- Select the 'Specify a CSS file' option and browse to the location
  where you uploaded your CSS file.
- Check the box for subsite inheritance if you want all subsites to use
  the CSS file.
- Click OK.

Reference: [https://www.kalmstrom.com/Tips/SharePoint-Online-Course/Publishing-Infrastructure-Alternate-CSS-URL.htm#:~:text=Add%20a%20custom%20CSS%20to%20a%20site&text=Click%20on%20the%20settings%20gear,you%20uploaded%20your%20CSS%20file](https://www.kalmstrom.com/Tips/SharePoint-Online-Course/Publishing-Infrastructure-Alternate-CSS-URL.htm#:%7E:text=Add%20a%20custom%20CSS%20to%20a%20site&text=Click%20on%20the%20settings%20gear,you%20uploaded%20your%20CSS%20file).

I understand you need a step-by-step guide to implement the CSS as well, but unfortunately I cannot provide this until I have a laptop at my disposal.